# exe file (created from jar) does not run on double click (command prompt program)

Tags: java, eclipse, command-prompt

I made an `.exe` file out of a command prompt program that I created. The original `.java` file can be launched in command prompt or in Eclipse without any problem.

I created a `.jar` file from it by using Eclipse Neon Release 4.6.0.

From this `.jar` file I created an `.exe` file by using [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) 3.8. When I double click on the created `.exe` file, it does not launch the command prompt automatically, and it does not run the created program.

I followed the steps [described here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse). I used these steps to create programs with a GUI, and those programs worked fine. This command prompt program does not.

Is it possible that command prompt programs cannot be run this way? Or if there is a solution for this problem, can you please help me with it?

Comment: you dont need any exe files, you need to create a jar file and then run it on cmd "java -jar yourjar" or double clicking the jar file (you need to check what program is associated with jar files in your operating system)

Comment: @Carlos that would require Java being installed on the machine. The point of making an .exe is that it requires no external dependencies

Comment: Ok now I get what you want, but with the wikihow you are following you are still needing java installed (jre)  so the only difference is the extension of the file (jar and exe)

Comment: @Carlos: Double-clicking a JAR also won't work with console applications that don't show a GUI window, for the very same reason why CsJoe has this problem here (it's linked to `javaw`, not `java`).

Comment: @Carlos the jre has to be installed on the machine that **builds** the executable. On the machine the .exe is run, Launch4j apparently uses a bundled jre or searches for one if it's installed

Answer (score 2):

According to the Launch4J docs (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html), you need to use:

```
launch4jc.exe
```

(*note the `c`*)

which no doubt wraps `java.exe` instead of `javaw.exe`

Answer (score 0):

> I used these steps to create programs with a GUI, and those programs worked fine. This command prompt program does not.

Are you sure that your program in not so fast?
Open the promt and go to the folder, so running the '.exe' in the promt